# как сделать так чтобы была так чтобы через одну колонку былы красным

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]


Таблица умножения

Количество колонок



Количество строк


Отправить

```
    <?
     var_dump($_POST);
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            if(empty($_POST['col'])) {
                echo 'Колличество колонок не введено<br>';
            }
            if(empty($_POST['row'])) {
                echo 'Колличество рядов не введено';
            }
            
            $col = $_POST['col'];
            $row = $_POST['row'];
        }
    ?>

    <div class="table">
        <!-- <? echo $row?> -->
        <?for($i = 1; $i <= $row; $i++):?>
            <div class="table__row">
                <!-- <? echo $col?> -->
                <?for($x = 1; $x <= $col; $x++):?>
                    <div class="table__col <?= $col + $x/10 ? 'red' : ''?> <?= $col -  $x/10 ? 'green' : ''?> ">
                    <?= $i * $x  ?>
                </div>
                <?endfor;?>
            </div>
        <?endfor;?>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом остатка от деления при итерации) Четные красные, не четные зеленые... `if ($i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: спасибо большое тебе Jour все получился